# How to get a mini popup in UWP like the one in Groove music?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

In later versions of Windows 10, the Groove music media player got a mini player feature.
[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md871.jpg)

I was wondering what API groove music is using to get this mini window to also stay on top over all other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewmode?view=winrt-19041) in UWP apps. This will make the app window show in a compact overlay (picture-in-picture) mode.

You could use the following code to do that:

```
 if (ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsViewModeSupported(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay))
        {
            // Supported
            await ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterViewModeAsync(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
            //change the UI layout
        }
        else
        {
            // Not supported
        }
```

Please do notice you will need to adjust the UI layout after you've entered the compact overlay mode.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!